# Error on CiviCRM Activation. Can't Install CiviCRM

Tags: wordpress, error, installation, civicrm.settings.php, plugin

I’m trying to install a new copy of CiviCRM for Wordpress on Plesk Onyx. I get the following error when I try to activate CiviCRM after uploading the files to my server:

Warning: require_once(CRM/Core/ClassLoader.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/vhosts/ruinsideca.org/infoportal.ruinsideca.org/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm.php on line 877

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'CRM/Core/ClassLoader.php' (include_path='.:/opt/plesk/php/7.2/share/pear') in /var/www/vhosts/ruinsideca.org/infoportal.ruinsideca.org/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm.php on line 877

I don’t know why this error is happening or how to fix it. I’ve never come across something like this before. As a result, I can't even install CiviCRM on my server.

I'm running PHP 7.2.22, Wordpress 5.2.3, and CiviCRM 5.17.3.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Just to make sure, is there a file at `/var/www/vhosts/ruinsideca.org/infoportal.ruinsideca.org/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/CRM/Core/ClassLoader.php`? Maybe something didn't get fully uploaded. Or maybe the file owner/permissions are wrong?

Comment: The file exists. I set the permissions to allow everything on that file. It's still not working.

Comment: @com1tech I suspect the permissions are the problem. Try making Classloader.php permissions 644.

Comment: Classloader.php is set to 644. It still showing the same error.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your suggestions. I found that there was a plugin conflict that was causing the issue. After disabling the plugin, I was able to install CiviCRM.

Comment: Which plugin was it, out of curiosity? If it's a popular one than it may help others in the future to know :-)

Comment: I encountered this also, it was the plugin "CiviCRM integration for Caldera Forms" which I'd installed before CiviCRM and this caused the problem described above.

Answer (score 2):

Same happened to me. On installing new test CiviCRM under WordPress. The "CiviCRM Contribution Page Widget" plugin caused same error. Civi 5.27.1, WP 5.4.2,  php 7.2.24 on ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Comment: Is this an Answer or just a 'me too'

Answer (score 0):

I encountered similar error messages attempting to activate CiviCRM 5.28.0 (but not on Plesk).

The error in that situation was caused by a previous, failed installation attempt on the site this one had been cloned from.  Removing all CiviCRM files and tables then enabled the plugin to be activated correctly.